# Drag n Drop documents in SharePoint 365 Trial not working

Tags: sharepoint-online, drag-and-drop

I am not able to Drag n Drop documents in **Master Page Gallery** in SharePoint 365 Trial.

How to enable it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Custom scripting capabilities are disabled by default in the tenant. Because of that, you are not able to drag-drop in the master page gallery. It also affect other features such as not able to use Script/Content Editor webparts, custom master pages , page layouts etc. Have added link at the bottom of the answer. Open the section, `Features affected when scripting is disabled` in the link.

Go to the SharePoint admin centre.

Select Settings.

Under Custom Script choose below options and save the settings:

[image]

After that, open the SharePoint online powershell and run the below commands. You need to be SharePoint admin for the commands to work:

`Connect-SPOService`

then

Enter URL of admin site `https://tenantname-admin.sharepoint.com`

Then username and password and after that run the below command with your site collection specified.

`Set-SPOSite -Identity https://tenantname.sharepoint.com -DenyAddAndCustomizePages $false`

After that, wait for like 2-3 mins, close and open designer again. It should work.

Reference - [Turn scripting capabilities on or off](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Turn-scripting-capabilities-on-or-off-1f2c515f-5d7e-448a-9fd7-835da935584f)

Download link - [SharePoint online powershell](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=35588)

Comment: Is it related to drag n drop sure?

Comment: yes, please check the reference link, section `Features affected when scripting is disabled`.

Comment: Thanks!.It is working or not I'll come to know tomorrow as it stats it'll take 24 hrs to reflect the changes.

Comment: Welcome ! Now that you have enabled the setting from admin center, you should run the powershell, it will enable it almost immediately.

Comment: ok let me check.

Comment: You are right! it has started allowing me to drag n drop the documents in doc library but am not able to drag n drop documents in Master Page Gallary.Any solution?

Comment: cool, am not sure why its not working in the gallery, can you try doing it via SP Designer ?

Comment: Yes SP designer solved my problem of the bulk insert by letting me import the whole folder from the desktop.

Comment: As this answer solved the problem of drag n drop for document library other than master page gallery marking it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, that's in the design of "SharePoint 2016" model. Therefore it will be either a lot of clicking - or - you can also map your Master Page Gallery as a network drive, or open the Gallery in the Explorer View to faster handle the file management.

FYI other ([1](https://www.eliostruyf.com/a-new-way-of-developing-display-templates/), [2](http://sptrac.com/wordpress/?p=2988)) heroes have faced this limitation as well advocating for the more general limitation.

Answer (score 0):

Before you can upload or create files in a library, your admin must give you permission to contribute to the library. Also, some file types in the library are blocked for security reasons. See [Types of files that cannot be added to a list or library](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Upload-a-folder-or-files-to-a-document-library-eb18fcba-c953-4d45-8d90-8da66edeacdb) for more info.